# Почему не работает setcookie

Tags: php

Должен выводится блок при первом входе на сайт. При последующих - нет.

```
<?

if(isset($_COOKIE['tour'])){

print <<<HERE
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tour').click(function() {
            $('.tour').fadeOut(1000)
        }); 
    });
    </script>
    <div class='tour'>
        <img class='here_is_menu' src='../img/here_is_menu.gif'><br><br> 
    </div>
HERE;

}
else{
    setcookie("tour","tour", time() + 99999999, "/"); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по логике Вашего скрипта, он при первом запуске создает cookie, а при последующих (когда кука установлена), выводит блок. Если я правильно понял задание, вам нужно вывести блок там, где вы ставите cookie:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['tour'])){
    setcookie("tour","tour", time() + 99999999, "/"); 
    print <<<HERE
    ....вывод блока....
    HERE;
}
```

Comment: не помогло( вывод происходит каждый раз при обновлении страницы

Comment: @BedOmar Многое зависит от браузера и правильно заданого вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так будет работать

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['tour'])){
    setcookie("tour","tour", time() + 99999999, "/"); 
    print <<<HERE
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.tour').click(function() {
                $('.tour').fadeOut(1000)
            }); 
        });
        </script>
        <div class='tour'>
            <img class='here_is_menu' src='../img/here_is_menu.gif'><br><br> 
        </div>
    HERE;
}
```

Comment: Вот так будет как минимум notice, тот же вариант описан сверху.

Comment: оО это же empty с ним notice не бывает))) попробуй проверь и убедись. Этот вариант 100% рабочий, впрочем как и нижний.

Comment: да сорри тупанул